# Converting a Bitmap image to a matrix

Tags: c#, matrix, bitmap

In C#, I need to convert an image that I have already converted to Bitmap in to a matrix of the size of the image's width and height that consists of the uint8 of the Bitmap data. In another word placing the Bitmap data inside of a matrix and converting them to uint8, so I can do the calculations that I am intended to do on the matrix rows and column.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public Color[][] GetBitMapColorMatrix(string bitmapFilePath)
{
    bitmapFilePath = @"C:\9673780.jpg";
    Bitmap b1 = new Bitmap(bitmapFilePath);

    int hight = b1.Height;
    int width = b1.Width;

    Color[][] colorMatrix = new Color[width][];
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        colorMatrix[i] = new Color[hight];
        for (int j = 0; j < hight; j++)
        {
            colorMatrix[i][j] = b1.GetPixel(i, j);
        }
    }
    return colorMatrix;
}
```

Comment: I give this a try. I have already converted my image to gray scale, that is easy. Are you sure that this takes care of the headers of the Bitmap. My matrix has to be just pure values and not include the headers of Bitmap.

Comment: If you want it slow, you use `GetPixel`. If the image is not _small_ one has to use `Bitmap.Lockbits()` and then access the underlying data directly. Depending on the size of the image it might also make sense to use a specialized library (AForge.Net, Streamwave, OpenCV, IPP ...)

Comment: +1. While it is slow (as @igrimpe poited out) it is correct which is important quality of code (ignoring random path assignment).

Comment: Unfortunately b1.GetPixle(i,j) does not work as my image is already in Bitmap format and gray scaled. It can not convert Color to Bitmap format.

Comment: in that case show the parts of your code, where you create the grayscale bitmap. And I'd still suggest to checkout `Bitmap.Lockbits`, because its not only faster, but also gives you `byte` (as you stated in your question) and not `color`

Comment: Here is my method for converting to gray scale.
`public Bitmap ConvertToGrayScale(Bitmap source)
        {
           Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(source.Width,source.Height);
           for (int y=0 ; y<bm.Height; y++)
           {
               for (int x=0 ; x<bm.Width;x++)
               {
                   Color c =source.GetPixel(x,y);
                   int luma = (int)(c.R*0.3 + c.G*0.59+c.B*0.11);
                   bm.SetPixel(x,y,Color.FromArgb(luma,luma,luma));
               }
           }
            return bm;
        }`

Comment: This code is very slow can someone tell me a faster way to do it